# how do I install myself as owner in 14.04?

Tags: password, root

How do I install myself as owner?  The system keeps telling me I'm not authorized.  I put in my profile but that didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

What operation you are trying to do? You can run program as admin by typing `sudo programname` on a terminal. To open a terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.